# How to send an Alias output to both Screen, File and Email?

Tags: linux, bash, output, alias

myserver is an Alias

I would like to send its output to Terminal Screen, File stats-dd-mm-yy (with date in the name), Email

```
myserver | tee /mydocs/mystats/stats-dd-mm-yy.txt | less | /usr/bin/Mail -s "Admin Server Stats" "myemail@myemail.ex"
```

Thank you for help me

Comment: Aside: Inasmuch as this is a question about software *usage* (ie. how to use the command prompt as an end-user) more than a question about software *development*, you might consider http://superuser.com/ as a more appropriate forum in the future.

Comment: Also, asking how to generate a filename with a date in it as a hidden extra question is something that really should be its own question (in the very unlikely event that you couldn't find it asked and answered in our knowledgebase already).

Comment: i'm a newbie but i think that i want to quit by this community because every time i ask help there are ever critics, thanks however

Comment: Criticism should be taken to mean that we're encouraging you to comply with local norms in the future, not to mean that we're encouraging you to leave. The goal is to build a high-quality knowledgebase; that means setting high standards for both questions *and* answers -- but those standards shouldn't by any means be unattainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date=$(date +Y-%m-%d)
myserver | tee >(/usr/bin/Mail myemail@myemail.ex) "stats-$date.txt" | less
```

This isn't in any way specific to aliases. The magic, though, is *process substitution*: `>()` (a bash and ksh extension) to generate a file-like object connected to the input of a process. When using this in a script, your script must start with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`; and it must not be started with `sh yourscript` (which would force a baseline POSIX interpreter).

This syntax will be replaced with a filename, typically on Linux of the form `/dev/fd/##` or `/proc/self/fd/##`, which when written to passes content to the stdin of -- in this case -- `/usr/bin/Mail`.

---

Some additional notes:

- `YYYY-mm-dd` is a far less evil file format. `dd-mm-yy` doesn't sort correctly, and it's ambiguous with `mm-dd-yy`.
- `less` needs to be at the *end* of the pipeline: It doesn't write contents to its own stdout in a form intended for programmatic use, so you can't usefully pipe from `less` to something else.
- `mail` *also* needs to be at the end of the pipeline, since it also doesn't write content to its stdout. The reason our code works is that `tee` is splitting our pipeline out, so it effectively has multiple ends!

Comment: As a side note, process substitution also exists for input.  For instance, `cat < <(ls /)` would list the root directory, and pipe its output to `cat`.  In this case, the first `<` is a normal redirection symbol, and `<(ls /)` would be the file-like object connected to the output of `ls`, and the input of `cat`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I had not yet realized you could do that in comments.